# SVN checkout issue

Tags: svn

I have a project locally that had 3 files, .h, .m and a .xib.

I deleted them and created new ones. I then commited as usual to the SVN repo, and the files dont show up in any commit options.

But when Checking out the project, the 3 files are in red, as if they have been deleted.

I cant seem to overwrite them or replace them.

How is this issue solved?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a pure svn related question. Why have you tagged it as `iphone` and `objective-c`?

Comment: When you created the files after deleting it, did you create them using the same name or a different name? Usually the files listed in red means they are missing in the working copy but its there in the server.

Comment: I used the same name yeah. I followed NoAlias's post and I tried a new checkout and I get the same issue. 3 files are in red. They arent in the working copy? the thing is it is a fresh checkout from SVN. Why are they even there in red if the file exists. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Probably your local .svn or _svn folder is having some information about those files. Try a `svn cleanup` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Commit is required after a Delete before you add the new files.